# place text in td after drop down on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to place my ajax results in the td next to my drop down that calls the ajax onchange.  each row has a similar id where i want the text to appear (i'm sure there is an easier way).  here is what i have.

```
$(".select-service").on("change", function() {

        var service = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajax/getServiceDesc.php",
        data: {service:service},
    dataType: "json",
        success: function(results){

            console.log(results['Description'][0].description);
```

ive tried using $(this).next('td') but it isn't recognizing the $(this).  it comes back as undefined.

i've also tried $(id) - as i've set the drop down id above the ajax call.

the structure of the td is as follows.

```
var n=($('.detail tr').length-0)+1;  
var tr = '<tr>'+  
'<td>'+n+'</td>'+
'<td><select id="drop'+n+'" class="select-service" name="prodService[]"> 
<option value="">- Choose Service -</option><option value="1">- Choose 
Service -</option></select></td>'+
'<td id="desc'+n+'"></td>'+ 
'<td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</a></td>'+ 
'</tr>';
```

i'm trying to target the id starting with desc.  the ending number matches the id of the drop id.

how would i place my result in that td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("drop", "desc");
```

Now, you can use `$("#"+id)` in your function to access the element.

Comment: you may need to concat a hashtag... as it stands,  `$(14)` won't work I don't think...

Comment: @AshleyBrown - Correct. Thanks mate!